# Limit of series/n convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose we have bounded, monotonically decreasing $\epsilon_i$, such that as $i \rightarrow \infty, \epsilon_i \rightarrow 0$.

How can I show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \epsilon_i}{n} = 0$? Is this even necessarily true? Tried Kronecker's lemma, as well as comparison tests to no avail. Seems like a pretty fundamental fact to prove.

Comment: You don't need the monotone property. Proved three ways in the link above.

Comment: Don't you mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i }{n} = 0$. Otherwise it is trivial if the series is convergent  - which is not always true given your hypotheses.